# Getting started with Compiler Design

Tags: reference-request, compilers

This is the first time I will be studying compilers in depth. Can someone point me to best online resources (courses, articles, tutorials, video etc ) and books?

My main aim will be to do some practicals instead of just reading theory.-something where theory practical goes in parallel. So the reference must fulfill this expectations.

Comment: [The dragon book](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Compilers:_Principles,_Techniques,_and_Tools) is a classic (non-online?) reference.

Comment: @Juho the Dragon book is a bit old fashioned by now and way too long. I don't recomment it as a first course.

Comment: We don't have a strict policy for list questions, but there is a [general dislike](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2011/01/real-questions-have-answers/). Please note also [this](http://meta.cs.stackexchange.com/q/20) and [this](http://meta.cs.stackexchange.com/q/145/) discussion; you might want to improve your question as to avoid the problems explained there.

Answer (score 6):

Alex Aiken's [Coursera course on compilers](https://www.coursera.org/course/compilers) is very nice. I suggest to take it
and do all exercises. Another interesting looking online course can be found [here](http://www.saylor.org/courses/cs304/), although I have not checked it out in detail (I would be interested in opinions about it).

As to books, here are a couple.

- [Modern Compiler Implementation in Java](http://www.cambridge.org/gb/knowledge/isbn/item1170327/?site_locale=en_GB) (second edition) by Andrew
  Appel and Jens Palsberg.
- [Engineering a Compiler](http://mkp.com/news/engineering-a-compiler-2nd-edition-by-keith-cooper-and-linda-torczon), by Keith Cooper, Linda Torczon.
- [Basics of Compiler Design](http://www.diku.dk/hjemmesider/ansatte/torbenm/Basics/) by Torben Mogensen. It's free.